# setuptools removes the binary files , but keeps them in the tar

Tags: python, python-2.7

When i do

> python setup.py bdist

for my python project folder.I find that it creates the dist, build folder but after it creates the egg/tar it deletes the binary.
How do i keep the binary files? I can see that it removes the build folder at the end.

```
running bdist
running bdist_dumb
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/my_project_folder
copying my_project_folder/__init__.py -> build/lib/my_project_folder
copying my_project_folder/my_script.py -> build/lib/my_project_folder
installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb
running install
running install_lib
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/usr
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/usr/lib
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/usr/lib/python2.6
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/my_project_folder
copying build/lib/my_project_folder/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/my_project_folder
copying build/lib/my_project_folder/my_script.py -> build/bdist.linux-
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/my_project_folder/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/my_project_folder/my_script.py to my_script.pyc
running install_egg_info
running egg_info
creating my_project_folder.egg-info
writing requirements to my_project_folder.egg-info/requires.txt
writing my_project_folder.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to my_project_folder.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to my_project_folder.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to my_project_folder.egg-info/requires.txt
writing my_project_folder.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to my_project_folder.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to my_project_folder.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'my_project_folder.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'my_project_folder.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'my_project_folder.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Copying my_project_folder.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/my_project_folder-1.0.0_SNAPSHOT-py2.6.egg-info
running install_scripts
creating /root/workspace/my_project-rpm/my_project-v1/target/my_project-v1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/dist
tar -cf /root/workspace/my_project-rpm/my_project-v1/target/my_project-v1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/dist/my_project-v1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.linux-x86_64.tar .
gzip -f9 /root/workspace/my_project-rpm/my_project-v1/target/my_project-v1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/dist/my_project-v1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.linux-x86_64.tar
tar -cf /root/workspace/my_project-rpm/my_project-v1/target/my_project-v1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/dist/my_project-v1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.linux-x86_64.tar .
gzip -f9 /root/workspace/my_project-rpm/my_project-v1/target/my_project-v1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/dist/my_project-v1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.linux-x86_64.tar
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb' (and everything under it)
```

**The problem i am trying to solve** is to create a tar file of ONLY the binaries.
As of now able I am able to create the tar file with both *.py and *.pyc files(this comes by default with bdist command) I understand this is the feature of bdist command.
But i dont want the .py file in the end tar.

As long as i can get the access to the *.pyc files i can create the tar myself but setuptools doesnt let me keep it.

Answer (score 0):

do both.

```
python setup.py bdist build
```

or

```
python setup.py bdist
python setup.py build
```